# What is the meaning of folders with an arrow in a Github repository?

Tags: github

[image]

I am not able to open this repository, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Folders with an arrow can indicate two things on the Github UI:

- a symbolic link
- a git [sub-modules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

The difference between the two is that if it's a submodule the commit hash of the latest commit is added after the name of the folder.

[image: image of a symbolic link on the Github UI]
[image: image of a git sub-module on the Github UI]

> I am not able to open this repository, why is that?

In your posted example, what you see is a symbolic link and you cannot open in because probably it points to a location that doesn't exist on your computer.

Comment: but,i am sure it exists in my pc